# Get all the Attendance and Fullname even no attendance on date with daterange mysql

Tags: mysql

How to do this in Mysql to get all users even no records or absent on that selected date range?

attendance_tbl

| ID | user_id | time_in | time_out | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | 2022-01-01 17:00:00 | 2022-01-03 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 002 | 2022-01-01 08:15:24 | 2022-01-01 17:00:00 | 2022-01-03 08:15:24 |
| 3 | 003 | 2022-01-02 08:44:55 | 2022-01-02 17:00:00 | 2022-01-04 08:44:55 |
| 4 | 004 | 2022-01-03 08:40:22 | 2022-01-03 17:00:00 | 2022-01-04 08:40:22 |

users_tbl

| ID | user_id | f_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | John Doe |
| 2 | 002 | Jane Doe |
| 3 | 003 | Ronal Black |
| 4 | 004 | Lucy White |

Expected Output Daterange : from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-03
Will get all the Users Fullname

| ID | user_id | Date | f_name | time_in | time_out | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | Jan 1 2022 | John Doe | 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | 2022-01-01 17:00:00 | 2022-01-03 08:00:00 |
| 2 | 002 | Jan 1 2022 | Jane Doe | 2022-01-01 08:15:24 | 2022-01-01 08:15:24 | 2022-01-03 08:00:00 |
| 3 | 003 | Jan 1 2022 | Ronal Black |  |  |  |
| 4 | 004 | Jan 1 2022 | Lucy White |  |  |  |
| 5 | 001 | Jan 2 2022 | John Doe |  |  |  |
| 6 | 002 | Jan 2 2022 | Jane Doe |  |  |  |
| 7 | 003 | Jan 2 2022 | Ronal Black | 2022-01-02 17:00:00 | 2022-01-02 17:00:00 | 2022-01-02 17:00:00 |
| 8 | 004 | Jan 2 2022 | Lucy White |  |  |  |
| 9 | 001 | Jan 3 2022 | John Doe |  |  |  |
| 10 | 002 | Jan 3 2022 | Jane Doe |  |  |  |
| 11 | 003 | Jan 3 2022 | Ronal Black |  |  |  |
| 12 | 004 | Jan 3 2022 | Lucy White | 2022-01-04 17:00:00 | 2022-01-04 17:00:00 | 2022-01-04 17:00:00 |

Comment: Please _delete_ those external links and instead include all relevant sample data as _text_, directly in your question.

Comment: Please fix your sample table data, it's a bit confusing specially in the `users_tbl` the `user_id` column is in time format and the `user_id` in the `attendance_tbl` are blank.

Comment: @TheCoolCat I already edit the post.

Comment: @LightYagami check my answer.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Do you need the date range to be contiguous? In other words, if there are dates in attendance_tbl with no users in attendance, do you still want to see all the null rows in your resultset? How do you want to handle the scenario whereby a user has multiple attendance_tbl records for the same day (e.g. out for lunch and then back in)? Attendance tables can grow to be quite large, so avoid joining on unnecessarily coerced datetime values as they negate index use. Using `date(t1.datetime) = date(t2.datetime)` for a join is evil.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? What's not working with your attempts?

Comment: @nnichols I am using Mysql 5.7.33, date range must be contigous must be displayed the date even the user is absent or dindt time in on that day, lunchbreak is not an issue since its only 1 hour which I will datediff

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried it my code is:  SELECT attendance_tbl.created_at, users_tbl.last_name, attendance_tbl.time_in 
from users_tbl
  LEFT JOIN attendance_tbl ON users_tbl.id = attendance_tbl.user_id
                      AND 
 attendance_tbl.created_at >= '2022-01-15 00:00:00'
        AND attendance_tbl.created_at <= '2022-01-31 00:00:00'
        ORDER BY attendance_tbl.created_at DESC  but dnd'nt show the date which must be continously

Comment: Thank you for replying but please add the details to your question. This makes everything clearer for other people reading the question and answers, now and in the future. You did not specifically address my question about the need to display dates for which there are no users present. Example, if there are no entries in attendance_tbl for '2022-01-23' (a Sunday) do you still need a row for all users on that date? Or will everyday have at least one user present? Will there be multiple entries for a user who goes out for lunch? Do we need MIN(time_in) and MAX(time_out)?

Comment: @nnichols yes, the expected output is if you select date range from 2022-01-15 to 2022-01-31 which is they didn't time in or time out on that selected range according to my given table but their name must be present from Jan 15 to Jan 31  please see the expected output their names is like looped on every day from Jan1 to Jan 3 and yes we have Sunday shift, we didn't include time in and time out for lunch. Thank you.

Comment: Please add **all clarification** to your question by editing it. That makes it way easier to understand the problem

Comment: How many users are there? Can there be multiple rows per user per day, or will there always be only 0 or 1? What is the maximum date range you expect to run this query for? The cross join then left join approach performs very well when there is a high density of matches on the right hand side (i.e. most users are in attendance on most days). When the density on the right hand side drops, there are better options. Please add the answers to these, and all the other questions, as detail in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to include the absent data, we need to start by getting the date range for the desired period. Using a user variable to store and increment a counter value is a performant way of doing this -

```sql
SELECT
    '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL @row_number DAY `date`,
    @row_number := @row_number + 1
FROM `attendance_tbl`, (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS `x`
LIMIT 31 /* 31 days in January */
```

If you have a table with a contiguous integer sequence (auto-incremented PK without deletes), you could use that instead -

```sql
SELECT '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL (`id` - 1) DAY `date`
FROM `attendance_tbl`
WHERE `id` <= 31 /* 31 days in January */
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

We then add a cross join to build the full set of dates and users -

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL (`id` - 1) DAY `date`
    FROM `attendance_tbl`
    WHERE `id` <= 31
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
) d
CROSS JOIN `users_tbl` `u`
```

By cross joining between these two tables we get the cartesian product (all combinations of the two sets).  We then just take it a step further by using a left join to the attendance data -

```sql
SELECT
    `u`.`user_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`d`.`date`, '%b %e %Y') `date`,
    `u`.`f_name`,
    `a`.`time_in`,
    `a`.`time_out`
FROM (
    SELECT
        '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL (`id` - 1) DAY `date`,
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP(`date`, '00:00:00')) `begin`,
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP(`date`, '23:59:59')) `end`
    FROM `attendance_tbl`
    WHERE `id` <= 31
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
) d
CROSS JOIN `users_tbl` `u`
LEFT JOIN `attendance_tbl` `a`
    ON `u`.`user_id` = `a`.`user_id`
    AND `a`.`time_in` BETWEEN `d`.`begin` AND `d`.`end`
ORDER BY `d`.`date`, `u`.`user_id`
```

If your `attendance_tbl` can have more than 1 row per user per day then you will need to add `GROUP BY d.date, u.user_id` and aggregate_functions in the select list.

I have added `begin` and `end` to the derived table. This is to allow for index use for the join. This is not important while the `attendance_tbl` is small but will matter more as the table grows. Adding an index on (user_id, time_in) will make a huge difference to performance in the longer term.

[Here's a db<>fiddle for you to play with](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ad3beb5da48a59b7c198bc3f164a12ae).

To run this from PHP using PDO you could do something like this -

```php
<?php

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = "SELECT
    `u`.`user_id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`d`.`date`, '%b %e %Y') `date`,
    `u`.`f_name`,
    `a`.`time_in`,
    `a`.`time_out`
FROM (
    SELECT
        :START_DATE + INTERVAL (`id` - 1) DAY `date`,
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP(`date`, '00:00:00')) `begin`,
        (SELECT TIMESTAMP(`date`, '23:59:59')) `end`
    FROM `attendance_tbl`
    WHERE `id` <= :DAYS_RANGE
    ORDER BY `id` ASC
) d
CROSS JOIN `users_tbl` `u`
LEFT JOIN `attendance_tbl` `a`
    ON `u`.`user_id` = `a`.`user_id`
    AND `a`.`time_in` BETWEEN `d`.`begin` AND `d`.`end`
ORDER BY `d`.`date`, `u`.`user_id`";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$startDate = new DateTime('2022-01-01');
$endDate   = new DateTime('2022-02-01');

$interval = $startDate->diff($endDate, true);
$daysRange = $interval->days + 1;

// Execute the statement
$stmt->execute([
    ':START_DATE' => $startDate->format('Y-m-d'),
    ':DAYS_RANGE' => $daysRange]
);

$attendance = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: how to set specific to date? like I mean like from Jan 1 to Feb 1? because the daterange is dynamic according to datetimepicker.Thank you very much.

Comment: My query is a little more awkward for the date range as it is using start date and number of days in range. The first expression in the sub-query - `'2022-01-01' + INTERVAL (id - 1) DAY date` and the where clause `WHERE id <= 31` should be parameterised and then the values for `start date` and `days in range` passed to the query before execution. How you achieve this will depend on the language your client app is written in.

Comment: yes, I am using the PHP 8.0, Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but can I change this  AND `a`.`time_in` BETWEEN `d`.`begin` AND `d`.`end` to this   AND `a`.`time_in` BETWEEN '2022-01-16' AND '2022-01-31'? NOTE: date ranges is dynamic.

Comment: No, that is one of the criteria for the join from dates to attendance. The only bits you would need to change are the Y-m-d strings being passed to `new DateTime()`. If you receive your dates in a different format then you could change to something like `$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/16/2022');`

Comment: I have a question it is only stuck on 5 days It doesn't capture the date which is 2022-01-01 to 2022-02-01, I am very if I am not well using interval in mysql. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. In here I call the `attendance_tbl` twice, one for creating a list of date and users and the other for fetching the data (time in and time out). And by using `BETWEEN` as @nnichols suggested to filter the selected range you prefer which I just realized earlier.

```
select u.`user_id`, date(a.time_in) as `date`, u.`f_name`, b.`time_in`, b.`time_out`, b.created_at from attendance_tbl a
join users_tbl u
left join attendance_tbl b on b.`user_id`=u.`user_id` and date(b.`time_in`)=date(a.`time_in`) 
WHERE DATE(a.time_in) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'
GROUP BY `date`, u.user_id;
```

**RESULT**

```
user_id  date        f_name       time_in              time_out             created_at           
-------  ----------  -----------  -------------------  -------------------  ---------------------
001      2022-01-01  John Doe     2022-01-01 08:00:00  2022-01-01 17:00:00  2022-01-03 08:00:00  
002      2022-01-01  Jane Doe     2022-01-01 08:15:24  2022-01-01 17:00:00  2022-01-03 08:15:24  
003      2022-01-01  Ronal Black  (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
004      2022-01-01  Lucy White   (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
001      2022-01-02  John Doe     (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
002      2022-01-02  Jane Doe     (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
003      2022-01-02  Ronal Black  2022-01-02 08:44:55  2022-01-02 17:00:00  2022-01-04 08:44:55  
004      2022-01-02  Lucy White   (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
001      2022-01-03  John Doe     (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
002      2022-01-03  Jane Doe     (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
003      2022-01-03  Ronal Black  (NULL)               (NULL)               (NULL)               
004      2022-01-03  Lucy White   2022-01-03 08:40:22  2022-01-03 17:00:00  2022-01-04 08:40:22
```

For the `ID` column just create a table with `AUTO_INCREMENT` id and insert your selected data.

To format your date (if you really really need to) like the one in your example result, just change the `DATE(a.time_in)` to `DATE_format(a.time_in, '%b %d %Y')`.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21dc5/1)

Comment: Thank, but I forgot to mention that the date range is dynamic to filter from Jan 1 to Jan 30 how to do that?

Comment: Ah yes. If that's the case you need to create a temporary table for the selected range and join it with the attendance and user table.

Comment: No need for a temorary table. As you are using `date(a.time_in)` to create the date range just add a where clause based on that - `WHERE a.time_in BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-30 23:59:59'`

Comment: But he needs to display the `Absent` dates, so we need a `Data` for those dates to show... if we use the between it will only display the date which are present in the attendance table.

Comment: It's all I can think of. @LightYagami check my modified answer.

Comment: @TheCoolCat, I will please wait

Comment: @nnichols can you show us how?

Comment: @nnichols yes I already add the addional details on comments. Thank you.

Comment: @TheCoolCat Sorry, We are forbidden for adding additional tables on the database.

Comment: @nnichols okay okay I get what you're saying. Thank you for explaining. I modified my Answer again

Comment: You still have an issue with expressions in your SELECT list which are not in GROUP BY clause and contain non-aggregated columns which are not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @TheCoolCat, Thank you for answering, but I still got a problem if I set the date range to 2022-01-15 to 2022-01-31 doesnt displaying anything, even they didnt time in or out the f_names should be displayed.

Comment: @LightYagami you need to include it in your question. You must clarify your question so we can provide you the answer that you need.

Comment: @TheCoolCat, Thank you again for answering, as I mention on my comment that the date range is dynamic you can set the date range using customized date time picker.

Comment: @LightYagami You just change the dates in the where clause - `WHERE DATE(a.time_in) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'`. The dates here should be parameterised and then you just pass in the dates you want.